# How can I fax using a Network Fax from my Windows 7 based PC

Tags: windows-7, fax

I have a Kyocera FS1118MFP multifunction Printer, Copier, Scanner and FAX set up on our network. The thing is that I want to be able to send faxes from a pc on the network and am in a pickle as to how to get it to do so. I tried using Windows Fax and Scan however there is no provision to connect and use a standalone Network Fax there.

How can I get this set up - I can send faxes from the machine manually but if I want to lets say send a pdf as a fax I can't do it.

Comment: Please go back to your previously asked questions and accept suitable answers.  You'll find people become unwilling to help if you don't acknowledge their effort with a few reputaion points.  Just click the tick next to the answer that solved your problem.

Comment: I have different hardware, a Canon MX882 multifunction printer, but the same question. I want to connect it so my Win7 PC recognizes it as a true fax so Windows Fax and Scan can fax to it. I tried googling the topic but got so much noise it was not possible to determine if anyone has a reasonable answer.

Answer (score 1):

Install the software that came on the CD with the printer.  One of the options in the installer will set up a Kyocera Fax printer driver for you.

Comment: Fax printer driver is not the same as a device being recognized as a true fax which is required for Windows Fax and Scan to use the device.

Comment: The Kyocera installer installs two device drivers, one for the printer and one for the fax.  They show up as two unique devices.  I can't speak for Canon's setup.